# mvpvm and unity framework

Tags: c#, unity-container

I've followed the example of partygoldeditor c# to implement IoC on mvpvm.

I'm currently stuck because the implementation inside the example is using castle windsor instead of Unity framework, i am unfamiliar with IoC, how do i change the implementation to use unity instead?

i did a

```
 IFormAPresenter formAPresenter = presenterFactory.CreateFactory<IFormAPresenter>();

 Form formA =      formAPresenter.View as Form;
 formA.Activate();
 formA.Show();
```

but it says ResolutionFailedException

Code to initialize the unity container:

```
 unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
      unityContainer.RegisterType<IformAView, OptimisationMenuForm>();
```

unityContainer.Resolve();

Comment: can you add the code where you register the types within unity?

Comment: hi Andrew, ive edited the question with the code to initialize and register the type of the container